# Unable to convert WikipediaR package object to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, wikipedia-api

WikipediaR package offers a great function  to list page's contributors.

Package configuration

```
install.packages("WikipediaR")
library (WikipediaR)
```

Collecting contribs R'page

```
contribs_r_page <-  contribs(domain = "fr", page = "R")
```

The problem: How to convert my object *contribs_r_page* in a data.frame?

```
str (contribs_r_page)

List of 4
 $ call        : language contribs(page = "R", domain = "fr")
 $ contribs    :'data.frame':   219 obs. of  3 variables:
 ..$ user     : Factor w/ 143 levels "0x010C","109.213.170.237",..: 87 73  121 9 121 64 11 81 47 121 ...
 ..$ userid   : Factor w/ 111 levels "0","1017","1019240",..: 97 86 28 1 28 50 1 44 7 28 ...
 ..$ timestamp: Factor w/ 219 levels "2004-02-09T19:44:05Z",..: 219 218 217 216 215 214 213 212 211 210 ...
   $ page        : Named chr [1:3] "0" "50889" "fr"
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "ns" "_idx" ""
  $ testWikiPage:List of 4
 ..$ takeOnlyFirst: logi FALSE
 ..$ redirPage    : NULL
 ..$ test         : num 0
 ..$ warnMessage  : NULL
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "contribsClass"
```

What I tried:

```
contribs_r_page_df <- as.data.frame.list (contribs_r_page)
```

Comment: Great: `contribs_r_page_df <- as.data.frame.list (contribs_r_page$contribs)` or  `contribs_r_page_df <- as.data.frame(contribs_r_page$contribs)` work well. Can you make an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the str output we can see `contribs_r_page` list object contains a data.frame named `contribs`, so we can just access it as below:

```
contribs_r_page$contribs
```

Comment: @akrun converted my post to a wiki as it is a simple answer to a simple question and I was asked by the OP to make it into an answer, but I disagree this is a dupe. The dupe target is about subsetting a dataframe, in this post it is a list. Thank you for going through my posts and cleaning them up.

Comment: @akrun Do whatever you think is right. No need to ping me and report.